# Execution time, Load Time and Compile Time (Memory Managment)

Tags: time, compilation, load, execution

I am now studying Memory Management in the subject of Operating System.

I am confused about these 3 different memory allocation.

I am able to distinguish the difference of these 3 allocations, but what I want is some example of each allocation so it would increase my understanding.